# How to merge namespace has no exported interface in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, bull.js

I am using the queue lib Bull in TypeScript. Its definition is:

**node_modules/@types/bull/index.d.ts**

```
declare const Bull: {
  (queueName: string, opts?: Bull.QueueOptions): Bull.Queue;
  // something like above
};

declare namespace Bull: {
  interface Queue {}
  interface Job {}

  // some other non-exported interfaces
}

export = Bull
```

I want to merge the namespace `Bull` in my library and use it in another app.

**node_modules/myLib/index.d.ts**

```
import { Queue } from 'bull'

declare namespace Bull: {
  export interface Queues {}
}

export interface myInterface {
  foo: Queue | Bull.Queues
}

export = Bull
```

**myApp/foo.ts**

```
import { Job, Queues } from 'myLib' // Error, 'myLib' has no exported member 'Job'
```

According to the doc, namespace is a GLOBAL variable, and namespaces of the same name will merge their EXPORTED interfaces. So, how can I merge the namespace `Bull` from `@types/bull`? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the truth is that `@types\bull` is not really declaring a namespace.

Well, it is, but just to group a list of related types and export them together as the default export, so, what it really exports are the **contents** of the namespace, not the namespace itself. That's why you can import `Queue`, and use `Queue`and not `Bull.Queue`, which is what you should have to do if `Queue` truly belonged to a namespace.

Besides, I don't know what version of TypeScript you're using, but you shouldn't be able to use `export (...)` and `export = (...)` in the same file. Besides, when you add `export` to a file, it turns into a declaration file for a module, so, in the end, you have a module that exports a namespace as default, and then you can import `Queues` from `myLib`, but not `Job`, as `Job` does not appear anywhere in the file and therefore it is not exported.

To be able to merge namespaces in different files, you can't use imports or exports, just declarations, because **two modules can never contribute names to the same namespace**. By using `export`, you're turning your files into modules, and once you do so, namespaces in them do not belong to the global scope anymore, so even if they have the same names, they really belong to the scope of their own module and do not merge.

To do what you're trying to do, you'd have to have:

bull:

```
declare const Bull: {
    (queueName: string, opts?: any): Bull.Queue;
    // something like above
  };

declare namespace Bull {
    interface Queue {}
    interface Job {}

    // some other non-exported interfaces
}
```

myLib:

```
declare namespace Bull {
  export interface Queues {}
}

declare interface myInterface {
  foo: Bull.Queue | Bull.Queues
}
```

And now you truly have one namespace with the contents of both declarations:

test.ts:

```
const a: Bull.Queues = {};
const g: Bull.Queue = {};
const b: Bull.Job = {};
```

This way it would work, but, unfortunately, is not what you have. You should define `myLib` as:

```
import * as Bull from './bull';

export interface Queues {};


export interface myInterface {
  foo: Bull.Queue | Queues;
}
```

and then you can use:

```
import * as Bull from './bull';
import { Queues, myInterface } from './myLib';

const a: Queues = {};
const g: Bull.Queue = {};
const b: Bull.Job = {};

const instance: myInterface = null;
```

or, if you prefer,

```
import * as Bull from './bull';
import * as ExtendedBull from './myLib';

const a: ExtendedBull.Queues = {};
const g: Bull.Queue = {};
const b: Bull.Job = {};

const instance: ExtendedBull.myInterface;
```

But, in any case, you need to import from both `bull` and `myLib`.

Comment: Thanks. I am using a tmp solution which is `export { Queue, Job, ...} from 'bull'` in `myLib`. It's not a good way either. Seems I have to import `bull` and `myLib` separately. I will accept this answer because it explains why the merge thing doesn't work.