# Can an imported merged namespace be exported in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have a library with a number of [merged declarations](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) like:

```js
export class Foo {...}
export namespace Foo {
   export class Bar {...}
   ...
}
export default Foo
```

The merged namespace typically defines inner classes, errors specific to the class, etc.

I would like to re-export some of these declarations in my own library.  I am currently trying to do so with:

```js
import FooExt from './library.js'

export namespace Baz {
   export type Foo = FooExt
   export const Foo = FooExt
   ...
}
```

This successfully exports the values of the `Foo` namespace, but not its types; i.e.:

```js
import {Baz} from './mylib.js'

let x: Baz.Foo.Bar              // Error: Namespace '".../mylib".Baz' has no exported member 'Foo'.
x = new Baz.Foo.Bar             // Ok
if (x instanceof Baz.Foo.Bar) { // Ok
    // do something
}
```

Is there a way to export an imported merged namespace and preserve its types?

So far as I can tell, this is a different case to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49724861) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49724861).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The namespace can be exported using the `export import` syntax:

```js
import FooExt from './library.js'

export namespace Baz {
   export import Foo = FooExt  // <-- exports namespace including types and values
   ...
   // instead of:
   //export type Foo = FooExt
   //export const Foo = FooExt
}
```

See [the original answer](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35165) in the TypeScript GitHub project.